# Ionic 2 invalid page component: null (Cannot read params from an external URL)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I can currently only achieve this format as image shows:

[image: Sample]

However, I want to read the URL in this format:

`http://www.mysitename.com/resetpassword?key=xxxxxxxx&email=xxx@gmail.com`

I have tried DeepLinker, but it only supports `/` (splash) format, and does not support a question mark format.

How can I do this in Ionic 2?

Please help me out of this dilemma, thanks guys.

Comment: what is your requirement? after reading that what will do? do you need to pass it to the `http` request or what?

Comment: The story : 

When user clicked the link, and then, the link will redirect user to ionic 2 app, so the ionic2 app needs to get the url params (key and email) values from the url address bar in browser, and read the key and email value and send the API request to verify the key and email is matched with database key and email value

Answer (score 1):

There is no Ionic way.But you can do that easily using Javascript as shown below.Because browser vendors have implemented a native way to do this via [**URL**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [**URLSearchParams**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

**Play with** [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qhbQA5?p=preview)

```
let url = new URL('http://www.mysitename.com/resetpassword?key=xxxxxxxx&email=xxx@gmail.com');

let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

console.log(searchParams.get('key'));  // output: "xxxxxxxx"

console.log(searchParams.get('email'));  // output: "xxx@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Thank you very much but no there, because we need to assume user click the link from his/her mailbox, when the link come to Ionic 2 app is opened, because of the (/?) question mark inside the link, so the url is gone and instead with display the home page url, this is why I cannot get params from the url, because the url is already changed because of the question mark

Comment: Please give me some help @Sampath, I am really appreciate.

Comment: Hi @Sampath, I have tried deeper link, which does not work, I tried this way: 

links: [
        {
          component: ResetPasswordPage,
          name: 'Resetpassword',
          segment: 'resetpassword?'+'key=:key&email=:email'
        }
      ]

Comment: I don't know why you cannot use above method? if you know the url then you can easily get the parameters no? what is the issue there?

Comment: The problem is I cannot get url, when user click email link from email box, the app does not redirect to that path with parameter, because the usrl includes with question mark (... resetpassword? ...), so far I guess my issue is ionic does not recognise the ? mark, it only read / format, right?

Comment: the problem is that finally my url is http://www.mysitename.com/, but I actually need to get this url: http://www.mysitename.com/resetpassword?key=xxxxxxxx&email=xxx@gmail.com, so I cannot get it when user clicks the email link